# Button Action Repeating Twice After Clicking Once

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I created a Button Class for my game,based on **Slick** which is extends **MouseOverArea** Class.
I Used another class for perform action when mouse click on the button.
Now I have a problem with it.When I click on the button once,button action is repeat twice.

This is the override `mouseClicked` method code of my Button Class.

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(int button, int x, int y, int clickCount) { 
        if (isMouseOver() && stateBasedGame.getCurrentStateID() == stateID ) {
            for (ButtonAction ba : actionList) {
                ba.action();
            }
        }
        super.mouseClicked(button, x, y, clickCount);
    }
```

I use `ArrayList` for hold all action.
(I add only one `ButtonAction` listener for My created `Button` Object)
This is My `ButtonAction` class

```
public  interface ButtonAction {
    public void action();
}
```

This is how I add action to My Created `Button` Object.

```
   myButton.addAction(new ButtonAction() {
                @Override
                public void action() {
                //this line repeate twice
                    System.out.println("Click On Me.."); 
                }
            });
```

I need to know,is there something wrong with my code which is relevant to repeating button action

Comment: Are you using a Component Listener in your MouseOverArea?

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1. I would suggest you revise your `mouseClicked` implementation. Try adding `return` after you notify all your `ButtonAction`s. Right now you are executing `super.mouseClicked` every time, and this may be causing the double call for some reason.
2. If you don't want to have duplicate `Button` actions for a single button, maybe you should consider storing them in a `Set` and having meaningful `equals` method so you don't add duplicates.
3. Are you positive that `myButton.addAction` is invoked exactly once? You can verify this by debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the points ;)
I tried all the points before asking here. Specially I used only one action to  avoid my error.But it happen as before as. :/

Comment: And I guess you are sure that `mouseClicked` is not called more than once?

Comment: Can you Show your mouseClicked method?